# Regex only matches last part of date in match group 1

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following string:

`22/04/2020 14:10 by example@example.com`

And I wrote the following regex:
`^(\d{2,4}\/?)+`

Why does group 1 only match the last part of the date and not the whole date, and how can I fix this?

https://regex101.com/r/Pc4McX/1/

Comment: You are repeating the capturing group, capturing the value of the last iteration. Why not match the format? `^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`

Comment: Yes, that is also an option, but I was wondering it also could be fixed the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Ok I think I solved it by doing `^((?:\d{2,4}\/?)+)`

Comment: You can make it a non capturing group instead `^(?:\d{2,4}\/?)+` and it could possibly also match a `/` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Note that regex store all matches in the array - firstly check in your code all matches. 
I think that the data that you need - already matched - you just need to store it. 
Following the Regex101 - Full match - will be your arr[0].
If you are using PHP - check this regex-tester = https://www.phpliveregex.com/

My regex :

```
^(\d+\W)*
```

Comment: How does this solve my problem? This would match all numbers and A-Za-z0-9_